# Serialize complex xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I would like to serialize the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CrossReference>
<Object Name="Sensor01;">
<Location Name="Sensor01.GEN">
      <Member Name="GEN" Datatype="Sensor_Gen">
        <Comment xmlns="http://www.siemens.com/automation/Openness/SW/Interface/v5">
          <MultiLanguageText Lang="en-US">Pressure sensor 01</MultiLanguageText>
          <MultiLanguageText Lang="de-DE">Drucksensor 01</MultiLanguageText>
        </Comment>
      </Member>
</Location>
</Object>
</CrossReference>
```

I defined the Class as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Configurator.Models.XmlFile
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CrossReference
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public Object[] Object { get; set; }
    }
    public class Object
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public Location[] Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public Member[] Member { get; set; }
    }

    public class Member
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Datatype { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = @"http://www.siemens.com/automation/Openness/SW/Interface/v5")]
        public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public MultiLanguageText[] MultiLanguageText { get; set; }
    }

    public class MultiLanguageText
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("MultiLanguageText")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I works almost completely. Just the part cannot be serialized:

```
<MultiLanguageText Lang="en-US">Pressure sensor 01</MultiLanguageText>
<MultiLanguageText Lang="de-DE">Drucksensor 01</MultiLanguageText>
```

The attribute Lang can be serialized but the content of the MultiLanguageText tag not. The public property "Text" of the class MultiLanguageText is allways interpreted as null.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`[XmlText]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=net-6.0):

```
public class MultiLanguageText
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Lang { get; set; }

    // Not: [XmlElement("MultiLanguageText")]
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

See [this example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsTGCG).